# Cassandra - No Viable alternatve at input 'COPY' ([COPY]...)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to programatically COPY a csv file data to a table in Cassandra, using the below mentioned dependency in spring boot.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.15.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The code snippet below is how I'm trying to execute the COPY command in my cassandra instance.

```
    @Override
    public void copyData(String tableName, String filePath) {
    // Implement logic to execute COPY command to load data into Cassandra table
    String copyCommand = String.format(
            "COPY %s FROM '%s' WITH HEADER = TRUE;",
            tableName, filePath
    );
    log.info("Executing query: [{}]", copyCommand);
    session.execute(copyCommand);
}
```

When executing the query in Spring Boot with the DataStax Java Driver, the below SyntaxError was encountered. However, the same query executed successfully in the CQLSH within a Docker container, and the data was copied to the table without any issues.

> line 1:0 no
> viable alternative at input 'COPY' ([COPY]...)

Environment:

```
Spring boot version : 2.7.10
Java version: 17
Cassandra Docker: latest (6.1.0)
[This container is mounted to my local machine from where the csv is available to the container to execute]
```